# Converting a year-month column to date type

Tags: r

I have a column in a data.frame in R that looks like the picture and it is stored as a factor:
[image]

I need to create a new column in the data.frame that has a data type = date, where this date is the first day of the month. Any ideas of how to create this in an easy way?

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste(df1$Date, '01'), '%Y %B %d')`

Comment: Are you inputting from a file? IF so you need to add `stringAsFactors = FALSE` in the input file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `paste` to paste the day with the 'Date' column, convert to `Date` class using `as.Date` with the appropriate `format` argument.

```
  df1$Date <- as.Date(paste(df1$Date, '01'), '%Y %B %d')
```

For more info, you can check `?as.Date`, `?strptime`, `?as.POSIXct`

Comment: Thanks! Just want I was looking for :)